# Using multiple jQuery versions problem

Tags: multiple-versions, jquery

I am building control that uses last version of [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/). Problem is that whole system is build using jQuery 1.3.2, but i need to use jQuery 1.4.2 for jstree, also to prevent errors need "$" still pointing to jQuery 1.3.2 to make system works normally. I tried to solve problem like this

```
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

And it works, but when i added other control to form like "datepicker" that initialized via $("#id").datepicker it throws error **$("#id").datepicker is not a function**

When i inspect DOM variables through firebug all is ok - $ is pointing to 1.3.2 and datepicker function is registered.

What it can be?

Thanks

Comment: What specifically is preventing you from just using the higher 1.4.2 version?

Comment: it is impossible because a lot of features will be dead. I tried)))

Comment: have you looked at this. http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Problem was not solved, we decide to migrate to jQuery 1.4* Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone came to this by looking for unanswered questions, the answer was to simply upgrade to 1.4.*

btw: jQuery 1.7 has just been released... time to upgrade again ;-)